# How to reopen project viewer in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't figure out how to re-open the tab on the left (solution viewer) in IntelliSense Idea.

Anyone know ?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the left bottom corner you will find a small icon. You can either move your mouse over it and select `Project` or click on this icon to toggle the visibility of all tabs (which you can click on to open the corresponding view).

[image]

You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to toggle the Project View.